# Error while cropping image using Numpy

Tags: numpy, crop

i was try this code

```
import cv2
img = cv2.imread("image.jpg")
crop_img = img[100:200, 200:400] # Crop from x, y, w, h -> 100, 200, 100, 200
cv2.imshow("cropped", crop_img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

it work for few times..but suddenly it come out with this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "test5.py", line 7, in <module>
crop_img = img[100:200, 200:400] # Crop from x, y, w, h -> 100, 200, 100, 200``
TypeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '__getitem__'
```

anyone can help me..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `cv2.imread` cannot find the file name i[t returns `None`](http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/doc/py_tutorials/py_gui/py_image_display/py_image_display.html#read-an-image).
If `img` is None, then `img[100:200, 200:400]` will raise

```
TypeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '__getitem__'
```

Comment: so we need to set the path of the image as example '/home/pi/image.jpg' ?

Comment: Specifying a full path to the file may help, but there are other reasons why `cv2.imread` may be returning None. It could be that you do not have permission to read the file, or that the file does not exist.